# A Safari Bookmark Icon That Cannot Be Deleted

Tags: safari, bookmarks

The icon image (.ico file) for a particular Safari 5 bookmark, for **"accuweather.com"**, keeps appearing no matter what purging of Safari I try to do.

I've tried everything, repeatedly. "Reset Safari..." command with "Remove all website icons" (and every other option) selected. Restarting the computer. Deleting the bookmark, and then making a new one at the site. Every other website icon was purged long ago.

The accuweather.com bookmark is just a normal bookmark, made manually when I'm at the site (not a scripted bookmarklet).

I have dug through OSX preferences but can't find the place where Safari .ico files are stored -- where is that?

This is a serious issue because a uniquely-numbered .ico file can be used to track site visitors.

---

Ed:

No response here a day later... This is with Safari 5 Mac BTW. If anyone can reproduce this problem for accuweather.com or any other site please report this to Apple using the Safari "Report Bugs to Apple" function (in "Safari" menu). I won't be following up on this Superuser question further. Thanks, Jane.

Comment: exactly *how* can this track you? I think you're confusing cached files for local use only and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

```
find $HOME/Library/Safari/Icons -type f -atime +30 -name "*.cache" -delete
```

Comment: Can you outline shortly how to execute that and what the parameters are? Some people don't know how to access the console / manual. Thank you in advance... :)